# PySpark Dataframe: Unify Certain Rows

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm having some trouble figuring this one out

Here's a simple example:

```
+---+----+-----+
| Id|Rank|State+
+---+----+-----+
|  a|   5|  NJ +
|  a|   7|  GA +
|  b|   8|  CA +
|  b|   1|  CA +
+---+----+-----+
```

I'd like to format this dataframe in a way where if the same Id is in multiple states, have it only store one state. In this example, any row with Id "a" should have state "NJ" instead of "NJ" and "GA".

The result should be something like:

```
+---+----+-----+
| Id|Rank|State+
+---+----+-----+
|  a|   5|  NJ +
|  a|   7|  NJ +
|  b|   8|  CA +
|  b|   1|  CA +
+---+----+-----+`
```

How can this be accompished? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `first` windowing function like:

```py
w = Window().partitionBy("Id").orderBy("Rank")
df.select(col("Id"), col("Rank"), first("State", True).over(w).alias("NewState"))
```

This will put into `"NewState"` column the first state according to the rank within id group.
The same thing can easily be expressed in pure SQL, if you want to use it.

BTW, welcome to StackOverflow community!